# How to add vertical lines to the left of my text?

Tags: android, html, textview, blockquote

How to add vertical lines to the left of my text?
I am showing a blockquote html in a TextView dynamically.

[image: refer image].

Comment: You could also use a **compound drawable** (`drawableLeft`, in this case), and save on an extra View.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Please google for `android textview compound drawable`

Answer (score 1):

Place on left of your `textView` and use your desired dimensions and color.

```
     <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></View>
```

Comment: want to create textview dynamically, set text from html.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    <View android:id="@+id/view"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="1dp"
          android:background="#000000" />
```

use webview for Html text

```
    WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

here is the code you want

```
      String a = "You can ";
      String b = "change" ; 
      String c = "like this" ; 
      String d = "if want to make it bold"; 
      String sourceString = a + " " + "<b>" + b + "</b>" + " " + c + " " + "<b>" + d + "</b>"; 
      textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

it will look like

You can **change** like this **if want to make it bold**

Comment: want to create textview dynamically, set text from html.

Comment: without using webview

Comment: @BincyBaby You can add a `textview` and set text as `.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your html string"))`

Comment: what exactly you want to do. please explain @BincyBaby

Answer (score 1):

You can use `View`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <View   
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <TextView
   android:text="balblalblablalblablalblalb"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It will look like:

[image]

For showing `Html` you can do as following:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html string"));
```

Comment: want to create textview dynamically, set text from html.

Comment: You can create `TextView` dynamically like: `TextView t = new TextView(context);` than set `LayoutParams` based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: Add a Linear layout in a layout.
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

</LinearLayout> 
step2:In Activity , create TextView and a View dynamically  add to linear layout
 LinearLayout mylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Testing");

    View view = new View(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(5, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    mylayout.addView(view,0);
    mylayout.addView(text,1);
```

Hope it helps!